# Exibir imagem do PHP por load() ou html()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Criei um arquivo em PHP, na qual utiliza a biblioteca WideImage (com cabeçalho header("Content-type: image/jpeg")), para manipular imagens. Dentro desse arquivo, capturo alguns parâmetros via GET e crio uma imagem a partir desses parâmetros. Até aqui tudo funcionando.

O problema é que, preciso enviar esses parâmetros partindo de uma página externa a essa, e em seguida, essa imagem gerada no arquivo citado acima precisa retornar para essa externa.

Estou enviando tudo via AJAX, porém, tanto no método load() e html() do jQuery, a imagem gerada vem toda codificada, como se não houvesse o cabeçalho image/jpg.

Alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir isso? Abaixo tem o trecho do JS que escrevi.

```
  $("#start").click(function(){                                 
        var request = $.ajax({
                          url: 'gd.php',
                          type: "GET",
                          data: {
                                dados
                          },                                                    
                          success: function(data) {
                            //data = $.parseJSON(data);
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#gera-img').html(data);
                          },
                          beforeSend: function(){
                            $('#start').css("display", "none");
                            $('.loader').css("display", "block");                               
                          },
                          complete: function(){
                            $('.loader').css("display", "none");
                          }                           
                        });

         });
```

Comment: Há uma resposta na versão em inglês do stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468954/set-image-content-from-ajax-response)

Comment: Adicione o seu código PHP para análise.